# After I run "node index.js" instead of a link to the picture, I get only "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${result.IpfsHash}" without IpfsHash

Tags: javascript, ipfs, pinata

There is an `index.js` file that allows you to retrieve a link to an image stored in the pinata.

Here is the code:

```
const pinataSDK = require('@pinata/sdk');
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');

const pinata = new pinataSDK(process.env.PINATA_API_KEY, process.env.PINATA_API_SERCRET);
const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream('./images/cool-bear-#1.png');

const options = {
    pinataMetadata: {
        name: "Cool Bear #1",
        keyvalues: {
            customKey: 'customValue',
            customKey2: 'customValue2'
        }
    },
    pinataOptions: {
        cidVersion: 0
    }
};

const pinFileToIPFS = () => {
    return pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile, options).then((result) => {
        return 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${result.IpfsHash}'

    }).catch((err) => {
        
        console.log(err);
    });
}

const getMetadata = async () => {
    const imageUrl = await pinFileToIPFS()
    console.log(imageUrl)
}

getMetadata()
```

And after I run `node index.js` instead of a link to the picture, I get only `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${result.IpfsHash}`. I mean the link without `IpfsHash`. Why?

I have result of ipfs:

```
IpfsHash: 'Qme5RqGiPZPFA65xNdvinZisirAU1VisAzAwZFWAzatSJ8',
PinSize: 1204410,
Timestamp: '2023-02-27T15:45:03.015Z'
```

And I need to add `IpfsHash` (`Qme5RqGiPZPFA65xNdvinZisirAU1VisAzAwZFWAzatSJ8`) to "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/" and get the https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qme5RqGiPZPFA65xNdvinZisirAU1VisAzAwZFWAzatSJ8.

How to do that? Why `${result.IpfsHash}` is not working?

Answer (score 3):

Change the quotes (`'`) to backticks (`):

```
return `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${result.IpfsHash}`;
```